# Angular2-Materials: Importing MdSidenavModule breaks application?

Tags: angular, angular2-material

So after much fighting with versions, i have a fresh angular-cli started app, did everything following the Angular2-materials readme, got buttons and cards to load and compile and my app still loads properly.

I then added an Import for MdSidenavModule into my component, all is well.
At the top of my app.module file i then call the import for MdSidenavModule, and in the @NgModule i add  MdSidenavModule into the imports section as i did for buttons and cards.  Except when i do this and save, my app compiles properly but it never leaves "Loading..." and  enters into my component that should print "App works!" like the  default angular-cli app does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The error im getting in the console is

```
    zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/sidenav 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM1125:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/sidenav
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:30)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/sidenav as "@angular2-material/sidenav" from http://localhost:4200/app/app.module.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/sidenav(…)consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/@angular2-material/sidenav(…)
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdSidenavModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdSidenavModule } from '@angular2-material/sidenav';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

I have double checked and sidenav is installed, but i also reinstalled it just to be sure.  Not sure what im missing.

Comment: If your app doesn't load, there are errors. Check the console and add them to your post. Also, including some of your code will go a long way to getting someone to help you.

Comment: Sorry i realized i should have done that,  it seems to be a 404 not found even though the module is installed?

Comment: Everything looks fine in the code you posted so far. Can you add the 'User Configuration' section of your `system-config.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

I was dumb, i forgot to add it to the array of materialPkgs to get loaded.